# How to fix "An error ocurred while loading the archive." in Archive Manager in RHEL 7.6 when opening ZIP files?

Tags: zip, rhel

When I try to open a ZIP file in the Archive Manager, I get this error: "An error ocurred while loading the archive."

This issue is happening on a virtual machine running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.

Oddly, this did not happen to me prior to this year 2022. Things worked OK in 2021 and each year before.

How do I fix this error "An error ocurred while loading the archive?"

I reverted to an old snapshot of my RHEL 7.6 virtual machine and I can now open ZIP files in the Archive Manager with zero errors. I think a system setting was edited OR a newly installed program is causing the issue.

Comment: There is the similar bug reported on issue tracker of `Archive Manager`: [Error opening encrypted (password protected) ZIP archive](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/file-roller/-/issues/142)

Comment: This bug should be reported on issues tracker of `Archive Manager` [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/file-roller/-/issues). And probably it will be fixed with time.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably bug in [Archive Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Archive_Manager) which was previously called `File Roller`.
I encountered it when were trying to unzip password protected zip file under `Ubuntu 20.04` and `GNOME Archive Manager 3.36.3`.

I created the corresponding issue on issues tracker of `Archive Manager`:

- [Archive Manager: An error occurred while loading the archive.](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/file-roller/-/issues/194)